# Come tradurre: Billing information?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation, single-words

Buongiorno.

Come posso tradurre Billing information in italiano?

Google Translate mi da: Informazioni di fatturazione ma non suona bene.

Come posso dire altrimenti?

Grazie!

Comment: Dati di fatturazione può andare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potrebbe andare bene ***"estremi di fatturazione"***, visto che il termine "*estremo*" è legato ad un ambito commerciale e bancario.

Si potrebbe anche dire ***"riferimenti di fatturazione"***, ma questa alternativa  mi sembra un po' più forzata della precedente.